# Por que este FAB desaparece, mas não reaparece?

Tags: android, material-design

Estou tentando animar um FAB de forma que quando ocorre o scroll para cima, esconde o FAB e quando rola para baixo, ele reaparece.

Estou seguindo o exemplo destes tutoriais que são muito parecidos:

[FAB: Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons#animating-the-floating-action-button)

[Hide the FloatingActionButton when scrolling a RecyclerView](http://androidessence.com/hide-the-floatingactionbutton-when-scrolling-a-recyclerview/)

Esconder o FAB funciona, mas ele não reaparece.

No debug, percebi que quando o FAB é escondido, os eventos responsaveis pelo efeito esconde/mostra: `onStartNestedScroll` e 
`onNestedScroll` param de ocorrer!

Este é o layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvRunList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/rvRunList"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_add"
    app:layout_behavior="br.com.medamais.motonoix.FABScrollBehavior"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Este o código que esconde (e deveria mostrar) o FAB

```
public class FABScrollBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

public FABScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

    if(dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        child.hide();
    } else if(dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        child.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Dependencias do Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
 // Simple Location Library
 compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11'
 // keep play-services v. 10.0.1 while using smartlocation v. 3.2.11
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
 // material dialog for permissions
 compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.3.1'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Como fazer para reaparecer o FAB depois que ele some?

Comment: Está sumindo mas não está aparecendo, certo?

Comment: Exato. O comportamento deveria ser: 1) rolou pra baixo, esconde. 2) rolou pra cima, reaparece. Mas só esconde e como eu disse, os eventos deixam de ocorrer.

Comment: Tente comparar assim **else if(dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)**

Comment: @ReneFreak tem como voc"e colocar as depend"encia do seu gradle na sua pergunta?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski, eu já havia feito isso. O problema é que depois que esconde o FAB, o método que esta linha pertence não é mais chamado e portanto tanto faz se é INVISIBLE ou GONE.

Comment: @AckLay, já adicionei

Comment: Entendi, no primeiro link , ele chama o **super** no retorno! :  **return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL || 
            super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target,
            nestedScrollAxes);**

Comment: Eu encontrei um possível bug em relação as dependências, vou postar uma resposta e você testa ai. A lógica do FABScrollBehavior  está correta.

Answer (score 1):

A lógica estabelecida ao seu `FABScrollBehavior` está correta. Deve permanecer da maneira que você definiu. Porém fazendo uns testes aqui, encontrei um possível `bug` entre versões de bibliotecas de suporte do Google.

Você pode remover a *lib* `RecyclerView` das dependência, pois essa versão do seu `appcompact` já possui suporte ao `RecyclerView`. Eu suspeito que existem algum conflito impedindo que seu botão funcione corretamente. Veja como deve ficar:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
 // Simple Location Library
.
.
.
```

## Com a *lib* RecyclerView

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Sem a *lib* RecyclerView:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser fazer alguma comparação, coloquei o [projeto FABScroll](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/FABScroll) no Github.

Comment: Não resolveu, mas me deu uma ideia. Vou trabalhar nela e volto com a solução ou mais informações. Vlw mesmo assim!

Comment: @ReneFreak não sei, talvez tenha mais alguma lib que esteja fazendo conflito. As vezes penso que não faz muito sentido, mas testei, refiz, testei, e o resultado foi esse dos gifs. Dê uma olhada e me fale.